# How to redirect domain to https and add default language

Tags: apache, http, https, server, centos

I'm setting up an apache server and want to redirect several type of domain to https and also add default language zh_tw in url if zh_tw or zh_cn are not exists in original url

for example:

www.something.com/news -> https://www.something.com/zh_tw/news

something.com/news -> https://www.something.com/zh_tw/news

http://something.com/news -> https://www.something.com/zh_tw/news

http://www.something.com/zh_cn/news -> https://www.something.com/zh_cn/news

I use htaccess tester To test my code but it seems failed beacuse using different host will cause redirect ? Anyone can help me with this issue?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteRule !^(zh_tw|zh_cn)/ zh_tw%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your htaccess file looks fine. If the url does not contain the language code and starts with http, then first the user will be redirected to https and then he will be redirected to a new url containing the language code. So after two redirects, the user will be redirected to the correct page.

Two redirects cannot be applied at the same time. So the first redirect rule will be applied first followed by the second rule.